# What version of bash am I running

Tags: bash, osx

I tried to change default bash on OS X Mavericks,

- Installed new `bash` trough `brew`,
- run `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`,
- went to "Users and group" made sure that Login shell for my login points to the same, 
  added path to `/etc/shells`, rebooted machine.

now `echo $BASH_VERSION`shows `4.2.45(2)-release`

but `sh --version` still says `GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`

Which one is true?

And if the second one, then what am I doing wrong, why it wouldn't switch to bash I installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Version Info

Like this:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

**NOTE:** Use caution since `sh` and `bash` aren't the same thing. `sh` is Bourne Shell while Bash is Bourne Again Shell.

#### Where is it?

Also in your case when you run `sh` you're picking up `sh` from `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. The Bash you installed via `brew` isn't likely on the `$PATH`, it's in `/usr/local/bin`.

Always try to get in the habit of querying the system as to "where" on the disk a given executable is coming from.

```
$ type bash
bash is hashed (/usr/bin/bash)

$ type sh
sh is /usr/bin/sh
```

#### Expunging from hash

To get Bash to unhash the location of `bash` you can use the `hash` command:

```
$ hash -d bash
$ type bash
bash is /usr/bin/bash
```

#### The $PATH

You can make the newly installed Bash the preferred one by ordering your `$PATH` slightly different.

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: yes... it's still not showing the new version. It points to the old (hashed) one... How do I force it to use the new one?

Comment: @Agzam - see updates.

Comment: now it doesn't say hashed, but still points to /bin/bash

Comment: Oh... it worked when I deleted /bin/bash :)

Comment: @Agzam - That's the PATH. I probably wouldn't delete it. Just put your `/usr/local/bin` in the front part of the PATH. `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. The hash is just a look up that Bash maintains so it doesn't have to crawl the disk everytime.